# Splitting string by '],[', but keeping the brackets

Tags: python, string, split

Ive got a string in this format

```
a = "[a,b,c],[e,d,f],[g,h,i]"
```

Each part I want to be split is separated by `],[`. I tried `a.split("],[")` and I get the end brackets removed.

In my example that would be:

```
["[a,b,c","e,d,f","g,h,i]"]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the brackets after the split?

Desired outcome:

```
["[a,b,c]","[e,d,f]","[g,h,i]"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `str.split` removes whatever substring you split on from the resulting list.  I think it would be better in this case to use the slightly more powerful [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function from the `re` module:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> a = "[a,b,c],[e,d,f],[g,h,i]"
>>> split(r'(?<=\]),(?=\[)', a)
['[a,b,c]', '[e,d,f]', '[g,h,i]']
>>>
```

`(?<=\])` is a lookbehind assertion which looks for `]`.  Similarly, `(?=\[)` is a lookahead assertion which looks for `[`.  Both constructs are explained in [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Python is very flexible, so you just have to manage it a bit and be adaptive to your case.

```
In [8]:a = "[a,b,c],[e,d,f],[g,h,i]"
       a.replace('],[','] [').split(" ")
Out[8]:['[a,b,c]', '[e,d,f]', '[g,h,i]']
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but here is another way to go.

**Important note**: this is just to present another option that may prove useful *in certain cases*. Don't do it in the general case, and do so only in you're absolutely certain that you have the control over the expression you're passing into `exec` statement.

```
# provided you declared a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i beforehand
>>> exp = "[a,b,c],[e,d,f],[g,h,i]"
>>> exec("my_object = " + exp)
>>> my_object
([a,b,c],[e,d,f],[g,h,i])
```

Then, you can do whatever you like with `my_object`.

Provided that you have full control over `exp`, this way of doing sounds more appropriate and Pythonic to me because you are treating a piece of Python code written in a string as a... piece of Python code written in a string (hence the `exec` statement). Without manipulating it through regexp or artificial hacks.

Just keep in mind that it can be dangerous.